# How to get route parameters from Nuxt 3 server

Tags: typescript, server, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have one of the following API URLs. At the end of the day for my use case, it doesn't matter which of these URLs I would have to use, but currently neither work.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/track/TRACKID
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/api/track?id=TRACKID
```

How would I get `TRACKID` in the APIs code? The following code results in `undefined`.

```
export default async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
    console.log(req.id);
};
```

I tried to set up the file for the first URL in the following way, but that was unsuccessful as well. It just resulted in the URL being `http://localhost:3000/api/track/[id]`

```
PROJECT/server/api/track/[id].ts
```

For the second URL I used the following set up.

```
PROJECT/server/api/track.ts
```

Comment: You should try with custom endpoint via Express : https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-api-endpoint

Comment: also check this: https://dev.to/dabit3/creating-api-routes-in-a-nuxt-app-1kg1

Comment: Does t his work with Nuxt 3? The stuff you linked seems to focus on Nuxt 2.

Comment: it does. give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as url from "url";

const params = url.parse(req.url as string, true).query;
const {id} = params
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: Is this the "standard" way to do this in nuxt 3? I couldn't find anything on the official docs

Comment: @cub33 check Curtis Rabon's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: Updated my answer now that Nuxt 3 has released.

```
export default defineEventListener(event => {
  const query = getQuery(event)
})
```

https://github.com/unjs/h3 is the server putting the api together.

Answer (score 2):

## For newer nuxt3 dev's

The h3 route now give you a CompatibilityEvent instead of using req and res.

Therefore you can use it like this:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
     const id = event.context.params.id;

     // Use the id here
});
```